# Program files folder in 16.04

Tags: directory, installed-programs, location

I have seen executable .exe files for all programs installed in **Program files** folder for Windows OS. Is there any equivalent folder in Ubuntu 16.04 where I can find the executables of installed programs ?

Also, what is the extension of Ubuntu executables ? Thanks.

Comment: See this for additional info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard  . *nix systes in general have specific filesystem hierarchy standard and its been so basically since the beginning, since original Unix in the 70s

Comment: Unix/Linux in general (and Ubuntu in particular) doesn't use file extensions to manage file types, but rather embedded MIME types.  Most often executable files have no extension at all.